# Difference between data hub tabs in synapse studio

Tags: azure-synapse

I have a hard time understanding the difference between **Workspace** and **Linked** tabs
[image]

I have only worked with on-premise and mainly with SSMS, this is very new...

It seems like the **Linked** tab would be for external stuff; but I have uploaded the file myself; so it isnt really external...
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The Data Hub is available from the Synapse Studio left menu and is represented by the database cylinder icon.

There are two tabs in the Data Hub blade, **Workspace** and **Linked**.

> The Workspace tab is where you will find your workspace databases such as data explorer datases which is currently in (preview), Lake databases and SQL Databases.

[image]

> The Linked tab is where you find linked external datasets and integration datasets used in data flows and pipelines.

[image]

For more details, refer to [Access and analyze all data from the Data Hub in Azure Synapse Analytics](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-synapse-analytics-blog/access-and-analyze-all-data-from-the-data-hub-in-azure-synapse/ba-p/1972955).